# Vine-like plant that eventually melds with others of its kind?

Tags: plant-recommendations

Is there any crawling plant that, when it's crawling among others of its species, will actually grow into one another and eventually share veins?

Unrelated: this is for a project to provide a living shade canopy over a suburban street.

Answer (score 2):

Most trees have fungi that [share nutrients with them](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycorrhizal_network). Trees can share nutrients through these underground networks of mycelia or can do so in a more direct manner by grafting branches together.

If you had a vine with a woody stem structure you could probably graft together different plants or they might naturally grow together in a process called [inosculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inosculation) which is often found when you [pleach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleaching) trees together.

I don't know of any crawling plant that you could use but many trees and some vines are potential candidates.